# How to parse a datetime string to date using nestbost/Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have an string input like this **"29/04/2020 12:01 AM"**. it is string input using tempusdominus bootstrapdatetime picker. I used nestbost/Carbon composer package,  when I post and request it to my back-end(Laravel).I got this error:

`DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (29/04/2020 12:01 AM) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character`

this is my function to parse:
`$date = Carbon::parse($request->date);`

note: i want it to parse so that it can save to my database/date column/DATETIME datatype (ex. 2020-04-26 19:52:00)

is anyone have experience/know to solve this?

thanks, sorry for my English.

Comment: See `Carbon::createFromFormat()`

Comment: Okay, i will look